# Git checkout from a PHP website?

Tags: php, git, apache, nginx, git-checkout

Is it possible to checkout specific branches from a Git version control system using a PHP website? All I need is a single webpage that lets me select any of the available branches and do a checkout after pressing a button (after authentication ofcourse).

Making a script to list all the available branches and display the page is easy, but the PHP script does not have sufficient rights to run a Git checkout. I can run the webserver (either Apache or Nginx) as root, but obviously that would be far too big a security risk.

How can I initiate a Git checkout from a PHP web script with min

Comment: Would the checkout try to update the website itself or run in a data folder? Also might worth a look: https://github.com/kzykhys/PHPGit

Comment: Give the Apache user write access to a temp folder for your checkout and make sure `git` is not disallowed in `php.ini`. Permission problems can be solved..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution was to just chown the whole site to the apache user. Now your PHP script can run the git checkout.

This solution is not 100% ideal for security, because now buggy scripts can change scripts in your webfolder. The proper solution for this would be to write a daemon than runs as a privileged user and runs only very specific commands for the apache user on request. I only needed a solution for our dev webserver, so the daemon would have been overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Better set up a git server, using e.g. gitolite (search in Google). It even handles key setup and such for you.

Comment: This should be a comment.